# Há problemas com segurança ao implementar e usar "suplementos" no VBA (Excel)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, segurança

Devido aos problemas de segurança com macros no **VBA/Excel**, fiquei com dúvidas se o mesmo ocorre (ou algo similar) ao se adicionar um **suplemento** e **usá-lo posteriormente** em projetos do **VBA**.

Isso impactaria para um usuário que "rodasse" um sistema feito em **VBA** com este suplemento em seu computador? Ele deverá ativar alguns procedimentos de segurança ou não fará diferença?

Não tenho como testar agora, mas este suplemento, se foi aplicado em um sistema, ele fica pronto para uso por este usuário não requerendo qualquer ação adicional? Ele não teria de ativar o mesmo suplemento em seu **Excel**?

Existe a "**ProgressBar**", um suplemento que ativei e testei **sem ter de ativar nada em relação à segurança**. Então é seguro e indiferente a existência e ativação deste suplemento pelo usuário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo o suporte da **Microsoft** sobre "suplementos do "**Excel**", pode haver problemas sérios de segurança com a ativação deles.

> Privacidade e segurança para suplementos do Office

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/fp161165.aspx

Neste sentido, há vários cuidados que os usuários finais devem ter em relação a isso e não somente o desenvolvedor, cuidados esses similares aos cuidados que se deve ter com a ativação de "**macros**".

> Exibir, gerenciar e instalar suplementos nos programas do Office

https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Exibir-gerenciar-e-instalar-suplementos-nos-programas-do-Office-16278816-1948-4028-91e5-76dca5380f8d

Há indicações de cuidados a se tomar contra "**Hackers**".

Da mesma forma que para as **macros** os suplementos também apresentam "Configurações de Segurança", onde tanto o desenvolvedor como os usuários finais podem ativar ou não alguns parâmetros em seu **Office**.

> **Arquivo > Opções > Central de Confiabilidade > Configurações da
>   Central de Confiabilidade > Suplementos**

Ainda nas questões de segurança dos suplementos, pode-se requerer "assinaturas de fornecedores confiáveis nestes suplementos". Por outro lado, pode-se desabilitar as "notificações de segurança", o que não é nada recomendável.

Em relação ao que precisa ser feito no **Ofiice** dos usuários finais, alguns suplementos podem "travar", pois há um **controle de compatibilidade** onde a "Prevenção de Execução de Dados" do **Office** desabilitará este suplemento.

Isto pode ocorrer devido à política interna da área de **TI** de algumas  organizações (configurações de segurança interna, por exemplo).

De forma objetiva (resumida), é isso.